# string[] count is passed to ComboBox, but string[] value is not

Tags: c#, wpf, naudio

i've used a method,

```
public static string[] getMyStrings()
```

and passed it to a combobox like:

```
cmbMyBox.itemsSource  = getMyStrings(). //(more detail below)
```

the debugger  shows the strings have been added to the combobox, but when i look in the combobox the number of entries are there, but blank. anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

**my list of devices:**

```
public static string[] GetMIDIInDevices()
    {
        //get list of devices
        string[] returnDevices = new string[MidiIn.NumberOfDevices];

        // Get the product name for each device found
        for (int device = 0; device < MidiIn.NumberOfDevices; device++)
        {
            returnDevices[device] = MidiIn.DeviceInfo(device).ProductName;
        }
        return returnDevices;
    }
```

**The simple code to display it on my main window in WPF:**

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        cmbMidiDropdown.ItemsSource = NAudioMIDI.GetMIDIInDevices();
        //LoadMidiInDevicesIntoComboBox();
    }
```

**here's the XAML:**

```
<TabItem Header="MIDI Settings" Name="tabMidiSettings" Background="DarkGoldenrod">
            <Grid  Background="Honeydew">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="758" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,141,146,0" Name="cmbMidiDropdown" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="312"  ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
                <Label Content="Select Midi Input device" Grid.Column="1" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="143,141,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
```

**DEBUGGER OUTPUT:**

**GetMIDIInDevices()**

```
-       returnDevices   {string[3]} string[]
    [0] "MIDISPORT 2x2 In A"    string
    [1] "MIDISPORT 2x2 In B"    string
    [2] "Turtle Beach USB MIDI 1x1" string
    returnDevices[device]   "Turtle Beach USB MIDI 1x1" string
```

**cmbMIDIDropdown**

```
+       cmbMidiDropdown {System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox Items.Count:3}        
-       cmbMidiDropdown.ItemsSource {string[3]}      
-       [string[]]  {string[3]} string[]
    [0] "MIDISPORT 2x2 In A"    string
    [1] "MIDISPORT 2x2 In B"    string
    [2] "Turtle Beach USB MIDI 1x1" string
```

Comment: Please show few actual string values, prhaps there some special symbols

Comment: My guess is that you have binding within your XAML that is incorrect. Can you post your XAML as well?

Comment: Looks fine, given that the `ProductName` of the devices actually contains anything, you might want to check that. As noted your XAML might also be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the ItemsSource in XAML, and the `DisplayMemberPath` as well.  When you set the ItemsSource in code, you are not changing the DisplayMemberPath, so the combobox is trying to call each object's `.Name` property.   `String` does not have a `.Name`, so you are getting blanks.  Remove the `ItemsSource` and `DisplayMemberPath` from your xaml, and you should see the values you expect.

Comment: That worked!!
It seems I've forgotten to clean up a few of my experiments with databinding. Thanks for the help. That was a bit tricky. thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
cmbMidiDropdown.DataContext = NAudioMIDI.GetMIDIInDevices();
```

You're setting your `ItemsSource` to inherit the `DataContext` by setting the `{Binding}` on the `ItemsSource` property. In doing this simply setting the `DataContext` of your `ComboBox` to the listing of strings will allow the `ComboxBox` to populate accordingly.

Also, setting your `DisplayMemberPath` is not needed since you are setting the `ItemsSource` as a listing of strings versus complex objects and a `Name` property does not exist on the string class.

Comment: It doesn't seem to make a difference. The count is still there, but with no text.

Comment: If you call `cmbMidiDropdown.DataContext = NAudioMIDI.GetMIDIInDevices();` instead of `cmbMidiDropdown.ItemsSource = NAudioMIDI.GetMIDIInDevices();` in your code behind and remove your `DisplayMemberPath` reference but leave your `ItemsSource = {Binding}` it will work.

Comment: ah ok, so judging by the two answers given, it seems that DisplayMemberPath and ItemsSource = {Binding} clash with each other in some way(in this particular instance, at least)?

Comment: They don't clash per se. It's that your bound to collection is a list of strings and their is no `Name` property on that class. If you created a simple `Widget` class that had a `Name` property and your collection consisted of `Widgets`; you could leave everything as is within your XAML and simply set the `DataContext` as stated in the answer and it would work.